# Regex pattern to exclude timestamps

Tags: python, regex, ms-word, docx, regex-group

I have the following text:

```
Master of the universe\n\n(Jul 26, 2023 - 1:00pm)\n\n(Interviewee: Marina)\n\n\n\n(00:00:05 - 00:00:09)\n\n\t Alice: This project. Uh my job is to ask lots of questions.\n\n\n\n(00:00:10 - 00:00:11)\n\n\t Marina: What is it?\n\n\n\n(00:00:11 - 00:00:14)\n\n\t Alice: Uh uh impartially.\n\n\n\n(00:00:15 - 00:00:18)\n\n\t Alice: Uh so suddenly I don't work for a particular brand.\n\n\n\n(00:00:19 - 00:00:21)\n\n\t Alice: Uh I'm self-employed,\n\n\n\n(00:00:21 - 00:00:21)\n\n\t Marina: M M.\n\n\n\n(00:00:21 - 00:00:32)\n\n\t Alice: I do group interviews with lots of brands, from toothpaste to the product we're going to talk about today.\n\n\n\n(00:00:32 - 00:00:32)\n\n\t Marina: Okay.\n\n\n\n(00:00:33 - 00:00:37)\n\n\t Alice: Uh today we're gonna talk for an hour uh.\n\n\n\n(00:00:36 - 00:00:36)\n\n\t Marina: Okay.\n\n\n\n(00:00:37 - 00:00:39)\n\n\t
```

From above text, I want to extract the `name: text`. For e.g.:

```
Alice: This project. Uh my job is to ask lots of questions.
Marina: What is it?
Alice: Uh uh impartially.
Alice: Uh so suddenly I don't work for a particular brand.
Alice: Uh I'm self-employed,
Marina: M M.
Alice: I do group interviews with lots of brands, from toothpaste to the product we're going to talk about today.
Marina: Okay.
Alice: Uh today we're gonna talk for an hour uh.
Marina: Okay.
```

I am able to identify the timestamps from this regex code, but not exclude them:

```
(?:[\\n]+\(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\)[\\n\\t\\s]+|$)
```

I need a regex pattern that can exclude all the timestamps and other text, only keeping the `name: text` as shown above.

**EDIT:**
**I forgot to mention, exclude the lines that match the Interviewee name.**

**P.S: I do not want a python code to do a regex replace using the above pattern. I just a complete pattern to find matches for `name: text`**

Comment: Try using 2 capture groups `^\t[^\S\n]*([^:\n]+):[^\S\n]*(.+)`  https://regex101.com/r/lfI5L5/1 See https://ideone.com/DAwRGY, or a single capture group https://ideone.com/VGA28T

Comment: not working! 

regexr.com/7k8un

Comment: Yes, but where is this string coming from? Is this literally a backslash and then  an `n` char like `\n` or is it a newline character? How/where are you using this pattern?

Comment: Perhaps [`(?<=\\t\s)\w+:\s*[^\\]+`](https://regexr.com/7k8ut)

Comment: i am trying to load and open multiple docx and excel files and merge their contents together.  But i need to exclude the lines where the lines match the interviewee name.

Comment: So you need to exclude the lines where the interviewee name is `Interviewee: Marina` ? But these patterns will give you the `name: text` matches independent of the interviewee name

Comment: I think it would be easier to share the code that you are using with the expected results, as for now it is not clear (at least for me) what the format of the text is that you want to match. Also a small note that `[\\n] ≠ \\n`

Comment: If you are using the `re` module, I think you would have to do it in 2 steps if you want to dynamically exclude the Interviewee name. If you know the name upfront, then `\\t\s*([^:]+?)(?<!Marina):\s*([^\\n]*(?:n(?<!\\.)[^\\]*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/2EujKn/1

Comment: Yes, I am using re module.  But each docx file will have an interviewee name in beginning, that needs to be extracted and then lines matching that interviewee name should be kept, and others excluded from result.

Comment: @sifar But your question states `EDIT: I forgot to mention, exclude the lines that match the Interviewee name.` and now you to want to match the lines for that interviewee name? Did you try any of the patterns in your Python code? Can you update the question with the Python code that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Code : https://ideone.com/egOlTP

I would do something like this using `re`

```
pattern = r'(\w+): (.+)'

matches = re.findall(pattern, input_text)

for match in matches:
    name, text = match
    print(f"{name}: {text}")
```

this prints the pattern that you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Output :
[image]

**If you do not want any other (like Interviewee - Displayed on the output screen)**

replace the pattern

```
pattern = r'(\w+): (.+)'
```

with this

```
pattern = r' (\w+): (.+)'
```

Comment: this looks simpler and closer to what i am trying to do. What if i want to eliminate the lines that match the Interviewee name?

Comment: Just add a space before the pattern . [TestCode](https://ideone.com/2sy1RA) - pattern = r' (\w+): (.+)'

Comment: No I meant removing lines from result that match the Interviewee name.

Comment: May be you can add a if condition after matching --[Testcode](https://ideone.com/2sy1RA). Like get the interviewee value and sotre in variable and filter the matched values.

Comment: Keep in mind the `\w` is limited to just letters, digits and underscores.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I need a regex pattern that can exclude all the timestamps and other text, only keeping the `name: text` as shown above. ..."*

You can use the following pattern.

```
\t (.+?): *(.+?)(?:\n)+\(\d
```

> *"... exclude the lines that match the Interviewee name. ..."*

You'll need to capture this value first.

```
\(Interviewee: (.+?)\)
```

Here is an example, where *s* is the provided text.

```py
name = re.search(r'\(Interviewee: (.+?)\)', s).group(1)
d = []
for m in re.finditer(r'\t (.+?): *(.+?)(?:\n)+\(\d', s):
    if m.group(1) != name:
        d.append({m.group(1): m.group(2)})
```

Output

```
{'Alice': 'This project. Uh my job is to ask lots of questions.'}
{'Alice': 'Uh uh impartially.'}
{'Alice': "Uh so suddenly I don't work for a particular brand."}
{'Alice': "Uh I'm self-employed,"}
{'Alice': "I do group interviews with lots of brands, from toothpaste to the product we're going to talk about today."}
{'Alice': "Uh today we're gonna talk for an hour uh."}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though conscise, but not working! (https://ideone.com/gAeEB5)[https://ideone.com/gAeEB5]

Comment: @sifar, glad to help.  It's working here.